# We are using IOKit frame for battery related info but now we are not able fetch data like battery voltage and current capacity for iOS 12 beta 9

Tags: ios, battery, iokit

We are using IOKit frame for battery-related info but now we are not able to fetch data like battery voltage and current capacity for iOS 12 beta 9.
Please let us know if there is an alternate way for it.

Comment: What you mean by "not able" ? You should share your code and errors to help people helping you

Comment: @GIJOW The IOkit framework doesn't return the battery voltage and current capacity values

Comment: Code:io_service_t powerSource = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPMPowerSource"));
 CFMutableDictionaryRef batteryProperties = NULL;IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(powerSource, &batteryProperties, NULL, 0);NSDictionary *extensiveBatteryInfo = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)batteryProperties;[allInfo appendString:@"\n\n\nIOPMPowerSource Data\n\n"];for (NSString* dictKey in [extensiveBatteryInfo allKeys]) {[allInfo appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@",dictKey,[extensiveBatteryInfo valueForKey:dictKey]]];[allInfo appendString:@"\n"];
 }

Answer (score 0):

on iOS11:

```
io_service_t powerSource = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPMPowerSource"));
    CFMutableDictionaryRef batteryProperties = NULL;
    IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(powerSource, &batteryProperties, NULL, 0);
    NSDictionary *extBatteryInfo = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)batteryProperties;
```

gives a LOT of keys (Voltage, AtCriticalLevel, CurrentCapacity, MaxCapacity..) and so on...

in iOS12 ONLY remain this useless dict:

["BatteryInstalled": 1, "IOClass": AppleARMPMUCharger, "ExternalConnected": 1]

Comment: I guess those are not public APIs?

Comment: yes. removed. after all the mess people did about apple reducing battery stats... so now no one can read those values. :(